# Sofia-SIP: Session setup

Tags: sip, sdp, sofia-sip

Does anybody have experience at using Sofia-Sip?

I'm trying to answer incoming calls. I managed it to create a session, but no media stream is established...

Does anybody have a simple example about this? I've already looked at the CLI client of sofia-sip and at [telepathy-rakia](http://cgit.collabora.com/git/user/cassidy/telepathy-rakia/tree/rakia/media-session.c), which were both quite complicated.

I'm not too familiar with media yet. I'd like to answer an incoming call, and get the G.711 payload to further process it.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it out on my own, it's written there deep in the specifications of nua library.

You have to send the information about what media you support at latest in the 200 OK response to the calling party.

I can provide source code here if someone is interested. Otherwise I'm not making the effort to clean it for this purpose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425640/use-sip-protocol-in-xcode-using-sofia-library

Comment: please help me out , i am really in need to know about sofia , i need to create a project and i know nothing about this library , thanks in advance

Comment: hi @Atmocreations, I'm trying to understand sofia, but sofcli is deprecated, and doesn't work with INVITE that handling media. I know she needs gstreamer, but I didn't find a sample for this. pls give me some advices, and source code, if possible.
rgds.

Comment: @Loi Dang: Sorry, I gave up the project a long time ago and decided to write a specialized and reduced sip stack for the very specific need I had at the time.